# 7 digit number consisting of 7s and 5s

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all the 7 digit numbers that have only 5 and 7 as their digits and divisible by both 5 and 7. I have no clue how to use divisibility of 7 to solve this problem. DO i need to check all the 64 combinations?

Answer (score 4):

The number has to be of the form $abcdef5$. Putting a $7$ at either of the places $a,b,c,d,e,f$ gives a contribution $0$ mod $7$. Putting a $5$ gives a different contribution mod $7$ depending on the place where you put it. A $5$ at position $a,b,c,d,e,f$ gives a contribution mod $7$ of respectively $5,4,6,2,3,1$. Each number of the form $abcdef5$ can be identified with the subset of $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ of positions where a $5$ is put. For the number to be divisible by $7$ we require the sum of contributions mod $7$ from the first six digits to be $2$, as together with the $5$ at the end this will give us $0$ mod $7$. A quick check now gives the following:

Sum 2: $\{d\}$
Sum 9: $\{f,d,c\}$ $\{f,e,a\}$  $\{d,e,b\}$  $\{e,c\}$  $\{b,a\}$
Sum 16: $\{f,d,e,b,c\}$ $\{d,e,a,c\}$  $\{f,b,a,c\}$

So all the numbers are $7775775$, $7755755$, $5777555$, $7575575$, $7757575$, $5577775$, $5777775$, $5755575$ and $5557755$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that $7$ divides $1001$ to say that if $7$ divides $abcdefg$ it also divides $a+bcd+efg$ and you already recognized that $g=5$.  This gives you two unknown digits in each place and $5,7$ is interchangeable with $7,5$.  This reduces the possibilities to $27$.  I don't see a quick way to improve on that.

Comment: hi! ross, thanx for the reply, can you make it more clear how you come up with 27, I mean i got that with this condition we can remove one variable reducing our number to 32. But hows interchangeability helping?

Comment: moreover, can we use divisibility by 7 to reduce our problem, i am lost

Comment: I think you just have to try all 27 possibilities and see which ones are divisible by 7.  Then you can unpack the ones that work into the seven digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let a number satisfying the constraints be of the form $N = abcdef5$. We can expand this to $N = 5+10f+10^2e+10^3d+10^4c+10^5b+10^6a$.

Now, $N\pmod 7 \equiv -2+3f+2e-1d-3c-2b+a$

Say this polynomial is K. Calculating the max and min values of K,

maximum: $K = -2+3(7)+2(7)-1(5)-3(5)-2(5)+(7) = 10$ (substituting 7 for positive terms and 5 for negative terms to maximize output)

minimum: $K = -2+3(5)+2(5)-1(7)-3(7)-2(7)+(5) = -14$ (doing the opposite of the above)

So, the values for K when $N\pmod 7 \equiv 0$ can be $7,0,-7,-14$ (integers divisible by 7 that fit in the range of K)

Factoring, $K = 3(f-c)+2(e-b)+(a-d)-2$. Since any odd$-$odd=even, every difference of variables in $K$ will be even. Therefore, we can narrow down the values of K to only $0$ and $-14$ when N is divisible by 7. Since -14 is the minimum, the only value for which $K = -14$ is seen above, and plugging the respective variables to $N$ we get the solution $5777555$.

Now, for finding values of the variables when $K=0$: If we let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be $(f-c), (e-b), (a-d)$ respectively, the possibilities for $x_i$ are $2$, from $(7-5)$; $0$, from $(5-5)$ or $(7-7)$; or $-2$ from $(5-7)$. We get the equation $3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 2$, with the only possible solutions being $(0,0,2), (0,2,-2), (2,-2,0)$. Now, we can just list the number of ways to achieve each solution:

For $(0,0,2)$:
Case 1: $f=c=5, e=b=5, a=7, d=5$ -> gives solution $7555555$.
Case 2: $f=c=7, e=b=7, a=7, d=5$ -> gives solution $7775775$.
Case 3: $f=c=7, e=b=5, a=7, d=5$ -> gives solution $7575575$.
Case 4: $f=c=5, e=b=7, a=7, d=5$ -> gives solution $7755755$.

For $(0,2,-2)$:
Case 1: $f=c=5, e=7, b=5, a=5, d=7$ -> gives solution $5557755$.
Case 2: $f=c=7, e=7, b=5, a=5, d=7$ -> gives solution $5577775$.

Finally, for $(2,-2,0)$:
Case 1: $f=7, c=5, e=5, b=7, a=d=5$ -> gives solution $5755575$.
Case 2: $f=7, c=5, e=5, b=7, a=d=7$ -> gives solution $7757575$.

So, from these cases we found 8 numbers that satisfy the conditions in the original question and we got these by getting values of the variables for which $K=0$. However, we also found a solution when $K=-14$, and in total we get 9 numbers consisting of 7s and 5s that are divisible by both 7 and 5:

$5777555,7555555,7775775,7575575,7755755,5557755,5577775,5755575,7757575.$