# Number with digits 5 and 7

Tags: number-theory

This is an extension of the question - [7 digit number consisting of 7s and 5s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557119/7-digit-number-consisting-of-7s-and-5s)

How do I solve if I want to find all 15-digit numbers consisting of 5s and7s that are divisible by both 5 and 7?

Comment: I think the reasoning that Arthur (the guy who submitted the top answer in the question you linked this to) used should also work in this case. Of course, it'd be trickier because now there are $14$ digits to check instead of $6$, but it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want $n$-digit numbers.  As before, the number must end in $5$.  Now $10^d \equiv 1,3, 2, 6, 4, 5 \mod 7$ for 
$d \equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5 \mod 6$ respectively.  If $x_d$ is the number of $5$'s in the $10^j$'s place for  $j \equiv d \mod 6$, you need
$x_0 + 3 x_1 + 2 x_3 + 6 x_4 + 4 x_5 + 5 x_6 \equiv 0 \mod 7$  with
$0 \le x_d \le \lfloor (n+6-d)/6 \rfloor$ except $x_0 \ge 1$.  Given $(x_0, \ldots, x_6)$, you can then put $5$'s in  any $x_d$ of the $\lfloor (n + 6-d)/6 \rfloor$
places corresponding to $j = d, d+6, \ldots, d + 6 \lfloor (n-d)/6 \rfloor$
including  the $10^0$'s digit, and $7$'s in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, with $d_{15} = 5$ essentially we need:  $$d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}d_{4}d_{5}d_{6}d_{7}d_{8}d_{9}d_{10}d_{11}d_{12}d_{13}d_{14}d_{15}\equiv 0 \mod 7$$

Now, let $b_{i} = 0$ if $d_{i} = 7, 1$ if $d_{i} = 5$, giving

$$5 * b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}b_{4}b_{5}b_{6}b_{7}b_{8}b_{9}b_{10}b_{11}b_{12}b_{13}b_{14}b_{15}\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
$$b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}b_{4}b_{5}b_{6}b_{7}b_{8}b_{9}b_{10}b_{11}b_{12}b_{13}b_{14}b_{15}\equiv 0\mod 7$$
Converting powers of $10 \mod 7$ gives
$$6(b_{1}+b_{7}+b_{13})+2(b_{2}+b_{8}+b_{14})+3(b_{3}+b_{9}+b_{15})+(b_{4}+b_{10})+5(b_{5}+b_{11})+4(b_{6}+b_{12})\equiv 0\mod 7$$
Now with $b_{15}=1$, choose the remaining $b_{i}$ as you please, except for $b_{4}, b_{10}, b_{5}, b_{11}$ which we will need to satisfy:

$$(b_{4}+b_{10})+5(b_{5}+b_{11})=(b_{1}+b_{7}+b_{13})+5(b_{2}+b_{8}+b_{14})+4(b_{3}+b_{9}+b_{15})+3(b_{6}+b_{12})\mod7$$

The sum of two $b_{i}$ can only be 0, 1, or 2 so we can easily deduce the following:

If RHS $\equiv 0 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (0,0)$ or $(2,1)$
If RHS $\equiv 1 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (1,0)$
If RHS $\equiv 2 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (2,0)$
If RHS $\equiv 3 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (0,2)$
If RHS $\equiv 4 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (1,2)$
If RHS $\equiv 5 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (0,1)$ or $(2,2)$
If RHS $\equiv 6 \mod 7$ then $(b_{4}+b_{10},b_{5}+b_{11}) = (1,1)$

So there will be 1, 2 or 4 solutions for $(b_{4}, b_{10}, b_{5}, b_{11})$ for each of the $2^{10}$ free selections of the other $b_{i}, i \neq 15$.

This is easily generalised for longer numbers because we can always isolate an expression $(b_{r}+b_{s})+5(b_{t}+b_{u})$ on the LHS and solve for any choice of the other $b_{i}$

Comment: how do you know for which free selection what solution to take